# JavaScript function to get the next date from a calendar

Tags: javascript, calendar

Have multiple registered calendars in my database, each calendar has Its characteristic.

I have a screen that the inclusion of a file and via a dropdown I choose the schedule that the frequency of this file will respect.

Ex .: Daily, Weekly, Monthly and etc ..

The idea is when the user clicks on a specific textbox, a message appears indicating the next available date for the file.

Ex. Today is the 28th.

Balloon: "The next date is 04/29/2015 day" if the frequency is daily.

Can you help me build this function with JavaScript?

I tried to use the code below, but my main question is how to return the next date in the calendar function

Code:

```
function ShowTip(obj, msg, useBottom, maxWidth){
    try
    {
    window.status = msg;
    var msgTip = document.getElementById('msgTip');             

    if(msgTip)
    {
        msgTipText.innerHTML = msg;
        msgTip.style.zIndex = 9999;
        msgTip.style.left = obj.getClientRects()[0].left + document.body.scrollLeft - 2;
        msgTip.style.display = 'block';
        if (maxWidth != null)
            if (msgTip.offsetWidth > maxWidth) msgTip.style.width = maxWidth;
        if (useBottom)
            msgTip.style.top = obj.getClientRects()[0].bottom + document.body.scrollTop;
        else
            msgTip.style.top = obj.getClientRects()[0].top + document.body.scrollTop - msgTip.offsetHeight - 4;
    }
}
catch(e) {} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function like this to pass in an interval such as day, week, month and use a switch statement to change the date accordingly. Lastly the function can return a formatted date string to display to the user.

```
function addDate(interval) {
    var todaysDate = new Date();
    switch(interval) {
        case "daily":
            todaysDate.setDate(todaysDate.getDate() + 1);
            break;
        case "weekly":
            todaysDate.setDate(todaysDate.getDate() + 7);
            break;
        case "monthly":
            todaysDate.setMonth(todaysDate.getMonth() + 1);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return todaysDate.toLocaleDateString();
}
```

Comment: I have a function in C # that makes these validations, I can call this function in JS?

Comment: Yes this function can be called in Javascript to increment the date based on the interval they selected in the drop down

Answer (score 0):

Use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) which provides add/subtract functions, then convert timestamp returned by moment.js to JavaScript Date object with **toDate()**

```
<script src="//momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var now = moment();
  var tomorrow = now.add(1, 'day').toDate();
  var nextWeek = now.add(1, 'week').toDate(); 
  var nextMonth = now.add(1, 'month').toDate(); 
</script>
```

Moment.js also provides formatting functions, for example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var now = moment();
  var tomorrow = now.add(1, 'day');
  console.log(tomorrow.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
</script>
```